# OpenGL/C++ Store all texture assets in a separate class as static members

Tags: c++, opengl, static, textures, game-engine

I'm building a game in OpenGL, C++ and I have different sky-box textures for each level, etc...

Now, I have to dynamically change textures on level changes, but there cannot be any lag when I do.

Up until now, I held all textures in arrays in the corresponding classes, however, now, I realize that other class, sometimes, need same textures and holding them (and loading again in the first place) in a waste and a redundancy.

I have thought to create a singleton class (LevelsManager) with a static member array holding all textures(bitmaps). Yet I feel somewhat funny doing so...

Is it a bad practice, does it have any problems like leaks or so on...
Are there any better ways?

Comment: I have the feeling that http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ may be better suited for this kind of question. However, you should generally avoid the Singleton pattern altogether. As far as `LevelsManager` is concerned, in all my career every single class with the word "manager" in its name was a sure sign of bad design, or of the author not understanding *what* exactly it "managed". Try to replace the verb "to manage" with something else. If you cannot think of anything, then you have a design problem.

Comment: It looks like what you need is more a texture or resource manager, something that helps you sharing the ownership of the textures (with a ref counter for example).

Comment: ChristianHackl - Thanks, but it is more of a c++ concern than an opengl or gamedev one though... and well... singletons are sometimes good...
and @Jerem - Yes that exactly what I want, yet I don't know what is the best way to do it other than static member holding everything...

Comment: If it is a resource manager you're looking for, I'm guessing someone else already explained everything about them. The fist link I got on Google looks reasonable: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-resource-manager-for-game-assets-r3807

Comment: To avoid freeze you need to stream content, however you have to entertain the player until required content is ready, and in reality any streamed content is slower than "brute loading" (even if it freeze for a while)

Comment: In practice loading a 4 mega pixel texture won't freeze at all (at least on my laptop wich is old). What you may want to do, is just prepare the content by loading the file in a second thread and then brute load that array into your OpenGL driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a texture (so the time of the GL calls needed to create the texture) should not freeze in any visible manner the game. On my old laptop loading a 4 mega pixels texture (2048x2048 + driver side generation of mipmap levels) takes 10 ms wich is far from being noticeable (2Ghz cpu).

The freeze you feel is probably caused by the lag introduced by your hard drive (20-30 milliseconds to start loading first byte and then wait enough time to satisfy your HD transfer rate: 100 Mb/s => another 0,1 seconds wich is a bunch of frames and hence very noticeable). (*)

Your best bet is to load a texture in RAM memory using a separate thread, then just load your texture into OpenGL as you usually do.

It is possible to stream content to OpenGL using buffer orphaning or other tecniques however that's a bit hard if you don't feel comfortable with OpenGL and anyway that requires more time than loading it as usual.

The singleton usage may indicate bad overall design. If a class need a `BackgroundTextureManager` you could instead pass it in the class constructor using a smart pointer. however for a very small game it won't hurt, as long as you know Singletons are generally bad and you are doing a bad thing by intention.

*
*Note that I loaded raw data, in reality you could have compressed formats like PNG and JPG wich adds additional decoding overhead, the decompression part should be done still on the 2nd thread.*

Comment: Sorry for the ultra-late reply, thank you very much I indeed did the RAM loading and The constructor SP passing. Cheers!